# Swift: How to bring application from background to foreground?

Tags: ios, swift

Like in unit test `UI test` we can bring app back to foreground from background,

```
let myApp = XCUIApplication()
myApp.activate()
```

But how to do it in release mode.

Actually I have **beacon** device when I trigger the device it initiate a call on iOS app and move to call view but if app is in background it waits until app get to foreground and then switch UI view.

I added local notification but user have to tap that notification to bring app back to foreground to go to call view while I want to do it without user interaction like in `UI test` mode.

trying to access UI test code in release mode but still unable to do it.

Kindly guide

Comment: you can't. Apple doesn't allow you to hijack the users screen and force your app open. has to be done through a user interaction. You were on the right track with the local notification. You can't access those UI test functions outside of a test bundle

Comment: THANKFULLY it's not possible. Imagine the user experience? User works with some app, suddenly some other app hijacks the screen?